# Why can't Honeycomb devices see this app on Android Market?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I can't work out why our app does not show up in Android Market to Honeycomb tablets - neither 3G nor wi-fi only ones. Here are the pertinent sections of the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" required="true" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" required="false" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Link to your app? Have you checked what the market website tells about your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch all instances of "required" to "android:required".  Those attributes are part of the Android xml namespace referenced at the top of your manifest as "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" :)

Comment: d'oh - I could have looked at that for months without seeing the bleeding obvious ;) Thanks!

Comment: np.  I looked at it for quite a bit before answering :P